# Label each panel of Grid

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of figures that I would like to show as grid for a publication. I currently just export the figure as an eps and use another software package to add Labels (A,B,C,D) to each panel of the figure. This is rather tedious to do. Is there a way to label each panel in Mathematica? For example is it possible to label each panel of the following grid?

```
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];

b = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];

c = Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];

d = Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];

Grid[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, Spacings -> {1, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you want a `Grid` solution:

```
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
b = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
c = Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
d = Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];

col[text_, plot_] := Column[{text, plot}, Alignment -> Center]
labels = Text[Style[#, 18]] & /@ {"Sin", "Cos", "ArcSin", "ArcCos"};
Grid[Partition[col @@@ Thread[{labels, {a, b, c, d}}], 2], 
  Spacings -> {1, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: No need to make `col` a function; it already is one. :-)  You could also use `MapThread[col, {labels, {a, b, c, d}}]` or make `col` `Listable` and then use `col[labels, {a, b, c, d}]` directly.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you want

```
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Epilog -> Inset[Style["(a)", 18], 
    Offset[{-1, -1}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]];
b = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Epilog -> Inset[Style["(b)", 18], 
    Offset[{-1, -1}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]];
c = Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Epilog -> Inset[Style["(c)", 18], 
    Offset[{-1, -1}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]];
d = Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Epilog -> Inset[Style["(d)", 18], 
    Offset[{-1, -1}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]];
GraphicsGrid[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Spacings -> {1, 2}, 
Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for. Actually what I used is a combination from your and @Oska's response. I have a title for each of my plots in the figure, so I could just replace the title used in Oska's response with A-D slide that label to the left or right of the panel. All of the response solve my question so thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `PlotLabel`s for each individual graph:

```
labelstyle={Bold,18};
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},PlotLabel->Style[Sin,labelstyle]];
b = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},PlotLabel->Style[Cos,labelstyle]];
c = Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},PlotLabel->Style[ArcSin,labelstyle]];
d = Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},PlotLabel->Style[ArcCos,labelstyle]];
Grid[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, Spacings -> {1, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Labeled:**

```
plots = Plot[#[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}] & /@ {Sin, Cos, ArcSin, ArcCos};
labels = Style[#, "Section", 18, Black] & /@ {"Sin", "Cos", "ArcSin", "ArcCos"};
labeledplots = Labeled[#1, #2, Top] & @@@ Transpose[{plots, labels}];

Grid[Partition[labeledplots, 2], Spacings -> {2, 2}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Panel:**

```
paneledplots = Panel[#, #2, {{Top, Center}}, Appearance -> "Frameless"] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{plots, labels}];

Grid[Partition[paneledplots, 2], Dividers -> All, Spacings -> {2, 2}, 
   ItemSize -> {15, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Changing the 4 last parameters of `Partition` the output becomes quite flexible:

```
 Grid[Partition[Plot[#@x, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 12, Bold]] & /@
         {Sin, Cos, ArcSin, ArcCos, Tan}, 2, 2, 1, {}], Spacings -> {1, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]